# How to make modal stay on scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple pop up modal in my page, I want this modal to stay when scrolling the page.

Here is my modal

```
<div class="modale" id="ouibounce-modal" style="display:none">
            <button type="button" id="pop_up_close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <img id="pop_up" src="images/caly_popup.png">
</div>
```

Here is my solution

```
.modale {
    height: calc(100vh - 126px);
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
```

this is not working, what do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: please add position fixed for modale class

Comment: try  overflow-y: hidden;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```css
  

 .modale {
    height:100vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin:auto;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="modale" id="ouibounce-modal">
            <button type="button" id="pop_up_close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <img id="pop_up" src="images/caly_popup.png">
</div>
```

Comment: add height according to your need